# How to mount customised NTFS external disk in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ntfs, external-hdd

A few years ago, I customised my external hard disk partitions using a Windows PC. All of them are NTFS. For one partition where I plan to have my collections of old movies, I remember changing the block size from default to a higher size (a multiple of 4KB).

Last year, I formatted my PC to Ubuntu. Except for my movie's partition, I can access all others. Is there any way I can mount this drive without a Windows PC? So far, I have tried several approaches and failed multiple times. Any recommended tools, please?

Comment: What exactly did you try that failed ? For example, have you tried to install `ntfs-3g`, which is the Ubuntu package that contains a driver for NTFS partitions ?

Comment: Hi @Paul_Pedant So I have tried ntfs-3g to mount and drive gets mounted but I don't see any data in it nor I am getting any messages to report.